# Oracle SQL Automated Rows to Column Pivot

Tags: sql, oracle, automation, pivot

This is something simple that I guarantee I am over-thinking. I have an input data set with monthly data that looks like:

```
MTD    |  ID  |  State
-----------------------
Jan-16 |  1   |  A
Feb-16 |  1   |  B
Mar-16 |  1   |  A
Jan-16 |  2   |  C
Feb-16 |  2   |  B
Mar-16 |  2   |  A
```

MTD is a date field and each month is represented by the first of that month (Ex: April 2016 = 01-Apr-16).

I need to write a query that returns:

```
ID  |  Jan State  |  Feb State  |  Mar State  |  (Repeat for each month)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |  A          |  B          |  A          |  ...
2   |  C          |  B          |  A          |  ...
```

Because new data is added per month, I want to automate the query so I don't have to edit it when a new month of data comes out.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: what do you mean by automation in this context?

Comment: If the number of rows in the original table (and therefore the number of columns in the result) varies from one execution to another, you can't do this with standard SQL. You will need "dynamic SQL" (something that most professionals recommend against), or - best - you can get the report in any format you need it if you use proper, dedicated REPORTING tools,

Comment: @vkp - 'Automation' meaning that the query would look at the "MTD" column of the input to determine how many columns to add. This way, when a new month of data is added, the query would add a new column without needing an edit.

Comment: @mathguy - Thank you, that's the information I was looking for. Follow up question: If I were to bound this exercise and agree to only keep one year's worth of data, does the query become possible even if I do not have data for all 12 months? For example, say I wanted to include data for 2016. I have data from Jan to October, but am missing November & December. Would it be possible to write the query so nulls  show up in the Nov and Dec columns until data shows up in the input?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. If your Oracle version is 11.1 or above, you can do it with the PIVOT operator; otherwise you can do the same "by hand".

Comment: @mathguy - Okay, I follow your logic and think I know how to write that query. If you post your comments in an answer, I will mark it correct. As always, thank you so much for your knowledge and assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*See Comments to original question - the OP indicated he will be happy with a solution for a known set of values in MTD column.*

Demo (assuming the values in the MTD column are known beforehand):

```
with
     inputs ( mtd, id, state ) as (
       select 'Jan-16', 1, 'A' from dual union all
       select 'Feb-16', 1, 'B' from dual union all
       select 'Mar-16', 1, 'A' from dual union all
       select 'Jan-16', 2, 'C' from dual union all
       select 'Feb-16', 2, 'B' from dual union all
       select 'Mar-16', 2, 'A' from dual
     )
select *
from   inputs
pivot (max(state) for mtd in ('Jan-16' as jan_state, 'Feb-16' as feb_state,
                                                     'Mar-16' as mar_state))
;
```

**Output**:

```
ID JAN_STATE FEB_STATE MAR_STATE
--- -------- --------- ---------
 1 A         B         A
 2 C         B         A
```